# Error with gradle and new intellij installation (2023)

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

When trying to create or open a gradle project with intellij ultimate 2023 I got the following error message:

LocalVariableTypeTable has wrong length in class file org/codehaus/groovy/ast/tools/GeneralUtils

My project is a kotlin project with graddle as build tools with gradle.kts files

[image]

My gradle file look like this:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.20"
    application
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(8)
}

application {
    mainClass.set("MainKt")
}
```

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thx

Comment: Did it work in the previous IDE version? What are the JDK and Gradle versions you use? Check also - are there any errors in `idea.log` after reproducing (use action in Help | Show log in...).

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve the issue by running the repair binary located at the root of my installation.